# Can't change values in SSIS Transformation Script Editor

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, etl

Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

I'm trying to change a few values inside the Script Transformation Editor but they are grayed out and I can't modify them.

Here I'm trying to change `ScriptLanguage` to *Microsoft Visual Basic*:

[image]

Here I would like to change the length of this `HashValue` column

[image]

I've tried restarting visual studio as well as removing the script and adding it back to no avail.

**EDIT:** I figured out the second one by changing the data type to DT_WSTR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Issue**

*Note: Once you accessed the script editor window you cannot change the it's language.*

But you can change your scripts default language from visual studio options. All you have to do is go to *Tools* and select *Options...*.  Under the *Business Intelligence Designers* option, select *Integration Services Designer* and change the script language to whichever you prefer your default to be.

[image]

**Second Issue**

You cannot change the length column of type Integer:

- DT_I1 is relative to Sql tinyInt data type *(0 to 255)*
- DT_I2 is relative to Sql Smallint data type *(-2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767))*
- DT_I4 is relative to Sql Int data type *(-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647))*
- DT_I8 is relative to Sql Big Int data type *(-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807))*

Only length for `DT_STR` and `DT_WSTR` can be changed

**MSDN articles about SSIS and Sql data types:**

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036(v=sql.120).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Script Component Language**

The Script Component ScriptLanguage property should generally be editable, **UNTIL** you have used the 'Edit Script...' dialog (since this builds up the backing project which can't be converted automatically). Try creating a new Script Component and editing this value first, but I was not able to replicate this being disabled at the start with my copy of VS2015.

**Data Type Properties**

Data type properties are controlled mainly by the selected DataType. In this case, you have a four-byte signed integer (DT_I4), which doesn't have any other settings. Other data types have different properties, i.e.:

- DT_STR (string) can set Length and CodePage (character set),
- DT_WSTR (Unicode string) can only set Length,
- and DT_NUMERIC can set Scale and Precision.